# Incremental CSS Media Queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

Consider a stylesheet that resizes the page as the height diminishes using `media` queries and `transform`:

```
@media (max-height: 620px) {
    body {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    }
}
@media (max-height: 590px) {
    body {
    transform: scale(0.90);
    }
}
@media (max-height: 560px) {
    body {
    transform: scale(0.85);
    }
}
// and so on ...
```

The page "zooms out" as the window height diminishes, allowing the full content to be displayed on smaller screens.
If I want to support screens smaller than `560px` height, I need to add more `media` queries.

Notice that for each `30px` lost in height, we call scale with `0.05` less in the input.

**Question:** Is it there a way to define incremental media queries using only `css`?

**Follow Up:** If a pure `css` solution is not available, what would be the simplest way of accomplishing such effect in [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com)?

**Edit:** Thank you all for posting different solutions to this problem. I appreciate your help. Your answers helped me learn how to improve my code.

Comment: in Vanilla JS  `(window.innerHeight) / (document.body.clientHeight)` is the proportion you need.

Comment: i think you can use a css preprocessor like sass for this

Comment: scaled text looks blurred. may you better use `vw` and `vh` units for layout instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use `vanilla JavaScript` in this case.

So, each `30px` is `0.05`, or each `6px` is `0.01` from `650px` down.

It means an amount of `600px` is `1` in scale and that each `pixel` is `0.01/6`.

With all that information in mind, we can use `resize` event to calculate this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', changeTransform); // when resize, call changeTransform

var bodyEl = document.querySelector('body');

function changeTransform() {

  var scale = 1; // default scale
  if (window.innerHeight < 650) { // if window height < 650px, do magic
    scale = -0.83 + (0.05/30)*window.innerHeight;
  }
  bodyEl.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")"; // apply scale (1 or the calculated one)

}
```

Hope it can help you somehow.

Comment: Your answer is straight to the point and tackles the issue head on. I would only make a slight modification to scale, and set it to `scale = -0.83 + (0.05/30)*window.innerHeight`. This accomplishes reducing `0.05` in the `scale` for every `30px` lost in height.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Yes, I see. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using CSS alone. You can do this using JS by adding a window.onresize function to watch for resizing and scaling the `body` of the `document`. This solution also scales dynamically so you do not need to worry about breakpoints or @media queries.

```js
function updateScale() {
  let viewScale = window.innerHeight / document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  document.body.style = 'transform:scale(' + viewScale + ')';
  document.documentElement.scrollHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

window.onresize = function() {
  updateScale();
}
updateScale();
```

```css
body {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#block {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='block'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@NathanFries is correct, this isn't something that is possible with native CSS.

CSS includes [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for percentage-based values for your width and height, but you can't pass that onto the `scale()` function.

You'd then need to tie this to some `resize` event listener.

Here is a quick example that might accomplish what you're looking to do:

```js
// @see https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/9dcca95/explainer.md#feature-detection
// @example `elem.addEventListener('touchstart', fn, supportsPassive ? { passive: true } : false);`
var checkSupportPassiveEvents = function() {
    var supportsPassive = false;
    try {
        var opts = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
            get: function() {
                supportsPassive = true;
            },
        });
        window.addEventListener('testPassive', null, opts);
        window.removeEventListener('testPassive', null, opts);
    } catch (e) {}

    return supportsPassive;
};

var supportsPassive = checkSupportPassiveEvents();

var mapRange = function(fn, inStart, inEnd, outStart, outEnd) {
    if (outStart === void 0) {
        outStart = inStart;
        outEnd = inEnd;
        inStart = 0;
        inEnd = 1;
    }

    var inRange = inEnd - inStart,
        outRange = outEnd - outStart;

    return function(val) {
        var original = fn((val - inStart) / inRange);
        return outStart + outRange * original;
    };
};

var linear = function(x) {
    return x;
};

var minHeight = 320;
var maxHeight = 620;
var minScale = 0.45;
var maxScale = 1;
var screenHeightToScaleFactorInner = mapRange(linear, minHeight, maxHeight, minScale, maxScale);

var screenHeightToScaleFactor = function(height) {
    if (height <= minHeight) {
        return minScale;
    } else if (height > maxHeight) {
        return maxScale;
    } else {
        return screenHeightToScaleFactorInner(height);
    }
};

window.addEventListener(
    'resize',
    function(e) {
        var height = this.innerHeight;

        this.document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + screenHeightToScaleFactor(height) + ')';
    },
    supportsPassive ? { passive: true } : false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS solution you can consider `vh` and `vw` unit but it won't be possible with scale since this one need a unitless value.

A different approach would be to use `translateZ()` and some perspective to simulate a scale animation.

Here is a basic example. The result isn't accurate as I simply want to demonstrate the trick. Run the snippet full page and adjust the window height and you will see the element scaling.

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  transform:perspective(180px) translateZ(15vh);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
some text here
</div>
```

You simply need to find the correct calculation for the different values.

Comment: I do not think this demonstrates that this will work. Indeed, I do not think it *will* work. I have been trying to come up with a solution using translateZ, with no luck. I think you would need something like translateZ(calc(180px * (100vh / 650px) - 180px)) if you have a perspective of 180px and want no scaling with a window height of 650px. However, only a number can be used in the divisor of a "/" operation. A length is invalid. Also, at least one of the arguments in a * operation must be a length, so it seems impossible to me.

Comment: @MarkFisher I am simply demonstrating the *trick*. I never said it will work. By the way we can combine more translate and consider nested element and also add one media query to activate/descative the translate if the height is less than 650px. Since there is no trivial CSS solution I tried to find an approximation with only CSS.

Comment: When you said "You simply need to find the correct calculation for the different values." that implied to me that you thought it would work if you plugged in an appropriate value to translateZ().